Как вывести названия таблиц в QListView
Имеется база данных Postgresql, в нем имеются несколько таблиц,  через что можно вывести  названия  всех этих таблиц в модель QListView?* или же через что можно это реализовать.
*Чтобы в дальнейшем переключаться по таблицам внутри QListView и выводить содержимое в QTableView. Посмотрел все что возможно везде только выводят содержимое таблиц.

QSqlDatabase::tables()
